# updating a list with jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to update a list with jquery but for some reason the POST function returns wierd objects. any ideas how to retrieve the data from the POST answer?

```
 var ans = jQuery.post("mysite.com", {name: "John"})
 var cont = jQuery( ans ).find( "#content" );
 alert(cont);
```

and the page:

```
<?php
   echo "<div id='content'>";
   echo $_POST['name'];
   echo '</div>';
?>
```

it alerts [object], when i try to read all the field of the object with:

```
answ = '';
for( var key in ans ) {
   answ = answ + 'key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + ans[key];
}
jQuery('#somediv').html( answ );
```

any ideas how to get what i echoed on the other page?

EDIT:
i tried the following as you all suggested:

```
var ans = jQuery.post("mysite.com", {name: "John"});
jQuery.when(ans).then(function(answ){
var cont = jQuery( answ ).find( "#content" );
alert(cont);
});
```

and also:

```
var ans = jQuery.post("mysite.com", {name: "John"}, function(answ){
var cont = jQuery( answ ).find( "#content" ).html(); 
alert(cont);
});
```

but it still doesnt work. the alert simply doesnt show which means there is something wrong before it.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.post` returns a deffered, not the result of the request, because this is an asynchronous function and the script goes on while the request is handled.

One of the typical use of [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is to pass a callback which will be called when the request is complete :

```
 jQuery.post("mysite.com", {name: "John"}, function(ans){
    var cont = jQuery( ans ).find( "#content" );
    // use cont
 });
```

But, as your URL is "mysite.com", you might also encounter a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) problem. To fix that [you must set the relevant CORS headers on your server](http://enable-cors.org/).

Comment: hello, for some reason it never gets to the function that runs on the end. any ideas?

Comment: Do your browser receive a response ? (look in the network tab of the developer tools)

Comment: you are right my friend, for some reason it doesnt get the page.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have same origin policy problem ? See edit. You might also have an error server side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
var cont = jQuery( ans ).find( "#content" );
```

Use the following code:

```
var cont = jQuery( ans ).find( "#content" ).html(); 
 //to get the content use the .html() or .text()
```

Answer (score 0):

@dystroy is right.
you could also use the deffered:

```
var defer = jQuery.post("mysite.com", {name: "John"});
$.when(defer).then(function(ans){
    var cont = jQuery( ans ).find( "#content" );
    // use cont
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesnt work, please see my edit. any ideas why is that?

Comment: by "mysite.com" you have a valid request endpoint right? some REST controller or php script?...